# issues with passing FOR loop through GOTO loop to new command prompt

Tags: batch-file

This is my first post so I do apologize if I'm not explaining it well. Please let me know if I should re-phrase things or clarify something! I am also not exactly great with titles, so please let me know if I should change it.

To help myself explain the situation a little more, I'd like to clarify what the purpose of this is. As one of my hobbies, I help on an image archive. One of it's issues is that the only video format it supports is webm. This can sometimes result in badly converted low-quality videos by users whom have no idea how to convert, which then needs to be fixed later.

Because of this, I've been working on a bunch of batch files that could both speed up and potentially lower the amount of badly converted video, by minimizing the required user-input. You can check it out here if you'd like to:
https://www.nicklo6649.com/Public%20files/index.php?dir=Batchfiles/

One of the staff members mentioned how they'd like a way to start multiple conversion at the same time and let it convert an entire folder, as their CPU is powerful enough to do so. Which is then what I've been working on now for a few days.

My current problem with the script is the fact that I cannot seem to reliably pass the FOR loop to the new command prompts that it starts in the GOTO loop, in any way.

I don't mind having to rewrite the current script, as long as it's still able to start multiple instances of ffmpeg with the FOR loop and it's specified values.

The solution would be preferred to be in form of a batch or PowerShell script, although any other language is also fine, as long as it can work alongside the batch file.

I've tried the following:

starting cmd with the FOR loop In the GOTO loop with:

```
start cmd.exe <FOR loop>
```

saving the FOR loop in a text file before the GOTO loop, starting a new batch file named command2.bat in the GOTO loop that then takes the FOR loop in the text file and saves it to a variable, and then calls the variable:

```
Echo "<FOR loop>"> command.txt

command2.bat script:

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /p command=<command.txt
set command="%command%"
%command%
endlocal
pause
```

Saving the the FOR loop in another batch file before the GOTO loop, and then starting the batch file with the GOTO loop:

```
Echo "<FOR loop>"> command.bat
```

And this is the script itself.

```
:next1
rem used to specify the input folder which the FOR loop should look in
set /p input=Input:

rem used to specify the output folder which the FOR loop should look in
set /p output=output:

rem used to specify how many time the GOTO loop should loop and start a new command prompt
set /p amount=:

if "%amount%"=="0" echo fatal error, please retry && goto :next1 

rem this creates a folder for the temporary files ffmpeg needs to store while doing the first pass in two-pass
mkdir "temp files"

@echo on

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set loop=0
:loop
echo.
start cmd.exe for %%f in ("%input%\*.*") do ffmpeg -n -i "%%f" -c:v vp9 -c:a libopus -crf 20 -b:v 192 -pix_fmt yuv420p -pass 1 -f webm "temp files\!random!" && ffmpeg -n -i "%%f" -c:v vp9 -c:a libopus -crf 20 -b:v 192 -an -pix_fmt yuv420p -pass 2 %output%\%%~nf.webm
echo.
set /a loop=%loop%+1 
if "%loop%"=="%amount%" goto :next
if "%loop%"==11 goto :next
goto loop

:next
endlocal
del /q /f ffmpeg2pass*
del /q /f "temp files\*.*"

:end
choice /c EC /n /m "(E)xit or (C)ontinue"
if errorlevel 1 set exit=Quit
if errorlevel 2 set exit=Continue
if "%exit%"=="Quit" goto :exit
if "%exit%"=="Continue" goto :skip
:exit
exit
```

The expected output is that the script starts x amount of new command prompts, each using the same FOR loop that was defined in the script and uses the specified input, output and future selections, such as codecs.

Comment: while i would recommend converting to powershell ... why are you tagging this with `powershell` at this time? i don't see any PoSh in there ... [*grin*]

Comment: ah sorry... I guess I added that without even noticing it. Thank you. I'd like to learn PowerShell scripting although I'm having issues remembering and learning  it, compared to batch files, so I've just stuck with that so far.

Comment: thanks for fixing that! [*grin*] if you want to learn PoSh, take a look at `Learn Windows Powershell in a Month of Lunches`. the book is in the 3rd edition, but it covers all the ideas in PoSh up to v3 - and that was the big change.

Comment: @LobaDK I'd recommend that you first encapsulate the process before you try to make it run concurrently. For that I think you should put that `for` loop in its own file and call it with parameters. It looks like you need an input and and output parameter for that. Within that batch file, you'd use `%1` and `%2` to refer to those. Then, this top level file can prompt for the variables still if you want, and pass them along when it `call`s that one. The top level file can still do what it needs to, to spawn the children, but it will separate your concerns and simplify implementation.

Comment: Lee_Dailey Thank you for the book recommendation! There's a lot to read, but I hope that won't throw me off.

@briantist Thank you for the recommendation as well! Would it be possible if you could show an example with the %1 and %2? I'm still somewhat new to using these things, and have a hard time wrapping my head around on how exactly I do it.

Comment: @LobaDK, your code appears to be trying to run between `1` and `11` `cmd.exe` instances. In each instance you are running a `For` loop which invokes an `ffmpeg` command against every file located within `%input%\ `. So effectively you're running the exact same `ffmpeg` command against the exact same files up to `11` times; what possible reason is there for converting the same files, up to `11` times. Would it not make more sense to run one `For` loop with each `Do` opening a separate instance of `cmd.exe` invoking a `ffmpeg` conversion of a single file from `%input%\ `?

Comment: @LobaDK - you are most welcome! good luck ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Compo the script is not meant to run 11 loops/instances, it's there as an added failsafe in case you accidentally give the `%amount%` variable a 0 or non-binary input and ensures that it does not get stuck in the loop.

You are correct that it would take the same file in each new FOR loop, which is why I've changed `-y` to `-n` after ffmpeg which should fix that as it then automatically skips input files whose name matches that in the output folder.

I just tried your idea, however it seems to just skip it and continue processing the rest of the script

Comment: @LobaDK, I'm quite sure of what I've read in your code, once you've fixed `if "%loop%"==11 goto :next` to read `If "%loop%" == "11" GoTo next` or `If %loop% Equ 11 GoTo next`, you're specifically ending the loop after `11` iterations, even if the end user has input `24`! Also you should open a Command Prompt window and enter `cmd /?` to read its output. You'll note from it that to run a command specified by a string, you should be using `/C` or `/K`, you may also find it useful to include `/V:ON` and possibly `/Q` too, e.g. `) Do Start "" cmd /Q /V:ON /C "ffmpeg…"`.

Comment: @LobaDK are you sure we can remove the files `:next` label or `del` command. Because with `start` command the parent program will continue executing... Won't the ffmpeg.exe need those files anymore? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "tempdir=temp files"

:next1
rem Specify the input folder which the FOR loop should look in.
set /p "inputdir=InputDir: "
set "inputdir=%inputdir:"=%"

rem Specify the output folder which the FOR loop should look in.
set /p "outputdir=OutputDir: "
set "outputdir=%outputdir:"=%"

rem Specify how many time the GOTO loop should loop and start a new command prompt.
set "amount=0"
set /p "amount=Amount: "

rem Check if integer, else amount will be 0.
set /a "amount+=0"

rem Check if integer is 0.
if "%amount%" == "0" echo Please retry& goto :next1

rem Create a folder for the temporary files ffmpeg needs to store while doing the first pass in two-pass.
if not exist "%tempdir%" md "%tempdir%"

for %%A in ("%inputdir%\*.*") do call :encode "%%~A"
exit /b 0


:encode
setlocal
set "count=0"
set "imagename=ffmpeg.exe"

rem Run tasklist.
if %amount% gtr 1 (
    for /f %%A in ('tasklist /nh /fi "IMAGENAME eq %imagename%"') do (
        if /i "%%~A" == "%imagename%" set /a "count+=1"
    )
)

rem Check count of processes.
if %count% geq %amount% (
    >nul ping -n 10 localhost
    endlocal
    goto :encode
)

rem Set wait for 1 instance only.
set "wait="
if %amount% equ 1 set "wait=/w"

rem Encode with ffmpeg.
start "%ComSpec%" %wait%^
 cmd /c^
 ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -i "%~1" -c:v vp9 -crf 20 -b:v 192k -an -pix_fmt yuv420p -pass 1 -passlogfile "%tempdir%\%~n1" -f webm nul ^&^&^
 ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -i "%~1" -c:v vp9 -crf 20 -b:v 192k -c:a libvorbis -b:a 64k -pix_fmt yuv420p -pass 2 -passlogfile "%tempdir%\%~n1" "%outputdir%\%~n1.webm" ^&^&^
 del "%tempdir%\%~n1-0.log"
exit /b 0
```

This code uses `tasklist` to count the number of
`ffmpeg.exe` instances. If the count is greater
or equal to the amount entered, the script will
wait for 10 seconds and then try again with
`tasklist`. This allows the count of
`ffmpeg.exe` instances to be as many as
the amount entered.

#### ffmpeg code differences

- Audio encoding set as `-c:a libvorbis -b:a 64k`.
- Output of 1st pass saved to `nul`.
- Inserted `-hide_banner` to reduce console output.
- `-b:v 192` changed to `-b:v 192k` so the bitrate unit
  type is specified. Seems low bitrate, perhaps should
  be `-b:v 192K`.
- Inserted `-passlogfile` argument so log files have
  a known and possibly unique name to identify.
- The 1st pass log file will be deleted at the end
  of the 2nd pass.

Comment: Excellent, it the script itself works very well! Thank you! While it's really nice not needing to have to encase spaced directory paths with double quotes, doing it will result in the script exiting unexpectedly. While I don't know if it matters, I also noticed that after a few minutes, the script will begin to spit out errors about `setlocal` being full. However the major issue seems to be that ffmpeg ignores all the parameters given. I changed `libopus` to `libvorbis` to check this, and it used `libopus` anyways, suggesting that it's using pre-defined parameters, as if none are given.

Comment: Updated code. Double quotes removed from input paths. `endlocal` added to avoid `setlocal` recursion error. Audio encode to libvorbis, tested as OK.

Comment: I've now marked this as the answer as it does exactly what I was after and in what feels like an efficient way. I am very grateful for all the help and ideas everyone here has given me and wanna say thank you! I've made some personal changes to the code in what ffmpeg does to the videos, but other than that it's the exact same.

Comment: As I'll be adding this to my publicly available batch file that I've linked on said image archive I help on, I'd like to know if it's okay that I credit you, and if you'd actually like me to do so or not.

Comment: Success :). Thanks for giving me the chance to fix the bugs that you reported. Any credit is very much welcome. Cheers to the project!

Comment: Updated code as it would not do just 1 instance of `ffmpeg` as specified.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this can help. It might have to apply some modifications. As per edit in the main post I changed the switch `-y` per `-n`.

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:Pre_Main
::How many instances should be initiated. Limit hardcoded to 11.
::Input dir , Output dir.
set /p input=Input:
set /p output=Output:
set /p amount=Amount:

REM If not defined %amount% (
    REM echo Please specify a number of instances greater than 0
    REM goto :Pre_Main
REM )

if %amount% LEQ 0 (
    echo Please specify a number of instances greater than 0
    goto :Pre_Main
)

cd input

if exist ffmpeg_temp_files (
    rd /s /q ffmpeg_temp_files
) ELSE (
    md ffmpeg_temp_files
)

set "n_loop=1"

::
::End-Pre_Main
::

:loop
for %%f in (*) do (
    @echo on
    echo inside the loop... File: %%f n_loop: !n_loop!
    start "!n_loop!...%%f" ffmpeg.exe -n -i "%%f" -c:v vp9 -c:a libopus -crf 20 -b:v 192 -pix_fmt yuv420p -pass 1 -f webm "temp files\%%~nf_!time!_!n_loop!" && ffmpeg.exe -n -i "%%f" -c:v vp9 -c:a libopus -crf 20 -b:v 192 -an -pix_fmt yuv420p -pass 2 %output%\%%~nf.webm
    @echo off

    if !n_loop! GEQ !amount! goto :Pos_Main
    if !n_loop! EQU 12       goto :Pos_Main
    set /a n_loop=!n_loop!+1
)

:Pos_Main

endlocal

if exist ffmpeg_temp_files rd /s /q ffmpeg_temp_files
del /q /f ffmpeg2pass*

cd ..

choice /c EC /n /m "(E)xit or (C)ontinue"
if %errorlevel% EQU 1 goto :exit 
if %errorlevel% EQU 2 goto :Pre_Main

::
::End-Pos_Main
::

:exit
exit /b
```

Comment: Thank you for the script! I've tinkered a bit with it, however I seem to constantly have issues with it, and fixing one problem seems to just cause another. A lot of the times it seems to start the right amount of requested ffmpeg processes, however the FOR loop does not seem to work, and it instead only converts one video per process. e.g. if I select 4 instances, it also only converts 4 videos in total. A lot of the times it also for whatever reason seems to ignore some of the parameters I've given ffmpeg, such as bitrate.

I'm also not sure where else the ``del`` command can be moved to.

Comment: Think about it... It seems improbably that the `batch-file` itself alters the parameters of the ffmpeg executable (`bitrate`). "if I select 4 instances, it also only converts 4 videos" do you mean if you run 4 times the `batch` it converts 4 videos or if you type 4 as amount it converts 4 videos? I don't understand this part I don't see it clear enough. In case of the `del` command, after `start` command is executed the parent process is going to continue. So at some time, probably, is going to reach the `del` command when other of the "child" processes is still running.

Comment: And I don't know probably delete one of those temp  files that one of the child's process need. Then, can be that for that reason you get diferent results when executing the `batch`. Hope this can help you.

Comment: I mean when I type 4 as the amount. The ``del``command I guess can always just be moved near the end, after a ``pause`` and an ``echo`` telling the user to wait before proceeding. I'll keep tweaking this script and testing out some things. At the very least I should be able to perhaps merge parts of them together

Comment: Isn't that the expected result? You type 4 then you process 4 videos in "parallel". Do I mistake? Moving `del` after `pause` I think is a very good idea. Also, I realized may be you want to change change `cd input` to `cd %input%`.

Comment: Yes and no. My desired result with my script is that it opens/creates x amount of instances of FOR loops that each converts videos from the same folder until the entire folder has been converted, even if there were to be 100 videos in it. It would essentially be the same as launching a batch file with a FOR loop in it twice or more times.
Thank you once again for the ideas and the script!

Comment: Then basically you want another `batch` program that call this `batch` process. Make sure that any of this instances create an unique `temp dir` and move the `files` that are working on on that temp dir because each process runs independently. Then, delete those temp dir when the process is finished and move the files processed to other dir, but I feel `%output%` does that. Hope this can help.